# Office error: "We weren't able to register your device and add your account to Windows."

Tags: windows-10, office365

**Full error**

> Something went wrong
>
> We weren't able to register your device and add your account to
>   Windows. Your access to org resources may be limited.

**History**

Due to a local domain issue, I had to remove my PC from the domain and re-add it.  After that my user profile was broken so I used a tool to migrate it.  Upon logging in, all my settings were back but I was not logged into my Office 365 apps.  When I try to, I get the error above.

After lots of troubleshooting, I created a new local account on my PC and was able to successfully set up Office and login as expected.

**Question**

How can I fix my current domain-based Windows profile so that I can login to Office using my Office365 credentials?

Comment: There are certain limitations to Volume License activation, in particular, the number of activations that must happen at once.  Contact your network administrator for assistance.

Comment: Why was I able to "activate" it under a new local profile? I don't think this is a licensing thing...

Comment: Is your situation the one solved in the last entry on [this post](https://www.tenforums.com/browsers-email/68271-unable-sign-outlook-com-one-account-server-not-found-2.html)?

Comment: No, that mentions a "DatabaseNotFoundException" error which I don't get. Also, the fix is to login to outlook.live.com which I cannot do with an Office365 account.  That problem is in no way related to this as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ScottBeeson - Likely due to the fact the group policy was applied to the machine. You certainly can log into outlook.live.com with an Office 365 account.  Both are Microsoft accounts (not saying it will fix anything though)

Comment: You cannot login to outlook.live.com with a 365 account.  "That Microsoft account doesn't exist."

Comment: And which group policy would be causing this?  I also confirmed this is an issue on another machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old post but this might help someone out there.
I forgot I had an existing installation of Office 365 and I keep getting the above error. I ran these commands in CMD (open as admin):

```
cscript.exe "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office16\ospp.vbs" /dstatus
```

Take note of the last 5 digits of the product key. Then run this command:

```
cscript.exe "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office16\ospp.vbs" /unpkey:XXXX
```

(replace the XXXX with the last 5 chars of the prod key):

This is only recommended for users who have Office Apps with Office 365 license.

[Reference here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/odsupport/2015/05/01/how-to-reset-an-office-365-install-to-the-initial-activationinstall-state/)

Comment: I have since moved on and cannot replicate the issue or validate this answer, but it is clear, has references and a couple upvotes now, so I am going to accept it.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:

HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity\EnableADAL
REG_DWORD
Value: 0

This disables modern authentication for office applications.

Comment: Can you add some detail and explanation? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.